# I set my router to only allow access through HTTPS, and now I can't access it. Can I fix this without resetting the router completely?

Tags: networking, router, https

I have a Linksys E1000 router that I access through `http://192.168.1.1`. I set it to only allow access through HTTPS, and now when I try to access it through the web interface at `https://192.168.1.1` in Firefox, I get an error message that says "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading." Chrome tells me that the page is unavailable.

Am I accessing the router in the wrong way through HTTPS, or did I simply break it? If I did break it, can I fix this without doing a factory reset on the router?

I closed Firefox and cleared the cache, and when I browse to `https://192.168.1.1` I get a message asking me to confirm a security exception. I accept this, but then I get the same "connection reset" message. I can ping the router with `ping 192.168.1.1` (on Linux) perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try clearing your browser cache or trying another browser. You should be prompted to confirm a security certificate exception when using https. Rebooting the router couldn't hurt either.

Comment: Can you ping the router?  If not, it wouldn't be the first time that a Linksys router needs to be restarted.

Comment: @NewProgrammerJames Just a reboot, though, not a factory reset?

Comment: Just turn it off for 30 seconds then back on again.

Comment: I agree with Michael... just unplug it and let it sit for 30 secs and then plug it back in.

Comment: Just a thought, could it be possible the time on the router wasn't set before https was enabled and now the certificate offered up by the router has the wrong time stamp and looks to be expired?

Comment: @wbouzane Restarting the router worked if I accessed it through xombrero. No such luck with Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Awesome :) Glad you got back in. Most routers have a backup feature as well in case you do need to factory reset you can restore your settings pretty easily.

Answer (score 7):

I have Asus RT-AC87U and this happened to me too. I enabled under the Advance Settings → Administration → Authentication Method → just HTTPS. I thought that to log into my Router afterwards I just had to put in the URL bar the URL Address *https://192.168.1.1*

But instead I have to specify also the port, so it should be *https://192.168.1.1:8443* or *https://router.asus.com:8443*.

Comment: Same works for ASUS DSL N66U!

Comment: This worked for me, thank you.

Comment: Also for the Asus RT-N16. Thanks for this info; I never would have figured this out!

Answer (score 1):

Disable your antivirus (web protection) temporarily
Try using the IP instead eg 192.168.1.1:8443
Install certificate once you get in

Answer (score -1):

check your proxy settings in advance-connections-settings...mine was set to use system proxy settings which is wrong, so I put it to no proxy and problem solved.

Comment: Please provide more information

Comment: @yass such as? ...